# MongoDB Database-level Statistics

Tags: mongodb

I need to monitor/collect usage statistics at the database level in a MongoDB replica set. There are out-of-the box tools for monitoring usage at the instance level (e.g. mongostat) and at the collection level (e.g. db.collection.stats()) but is there anything in the vanilla MongoDB installation that will do the same at the database level?

Comment: How about [db.stats()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.stats/)?

Comment: db.stats() only provides size info, not usage.